# Given a list of items (different types), how do I separate those, so that each group contains only items with the same type

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a `List` of items of different types, how do I **efficiently** separate those, so each group only contains item of the same type?

`More details`

In java, I have a `List` of about 10000 items. There are 10 different **types** of item. **Type** as in property of value. For example, `List<Foo>`, then type is `Foo#getType()`.

I need to create zip-files that contain only one type of item.

Please give me some idea. Code are most-welcomed and appreciated, even pseudo-code. Thank you.

**Accepted Code taking the idea from Jon Skeet**

```
List<Foo> list = ...;
ImmutableListMultimap<String, Foo> grouped = MultiMaps.index(list,
    new Function<Foo, String>() {
        public String apply(Foo input) {
            return input.getType();
        }
});
for(String type : grouped.keySet()){
    //The below list will contains items with the same type.
    ImmutableList<Foo> fooListWithSameType = grouped.get(type);
    String zipName = getZipName(type);
    //Zip the list to a given file name
    zipList(fooListWithSameType, zipName);
}
```

Comment: Type as in class, or type as in "some property of the value"?

Comment: @Jon: type is some property of value. Like `List<Foo>`, then type is `Foo#getType()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Guava](http://guava-library.googlecode.com)'s `MultiMap` functionality with [`MultiMaps.index`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29), so using your `Foo.getType()` example, if it returns a string:

```
ImmutableListMultimap<String, Foo> grouped = MultiMaps.index(list,
    new Function<Foo, String>() {
        public String apply(Foo input) {
            return input.getType();
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jon. I have decide to implement your solution, however I cant test it yet since the system I design take a bit of time to build up. Therefore I look around and write some code to demonstrate my understanding about `ImmutableListMultimap`. I post these code on my original question. Will you take a look at it and let me know if my understand is correct, Jon? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer will let you sort them by type into a new in-memory structure, but if you just need zip files per type, why not

```
Map<Type, ZipOutputStream> zips = ...;
for (Foo foo : list) {
    zips.get(foo.getType())... // add the entry and write the content
}
```

Comment: uhmmm...  I like this. Let me write some codes. So you make one pass to the list to build the `Map<Type, ZipOutputStream> zips`, then you make the second pass through the List again, adding individual file into the correct `ZipOutputStream`. This is clever.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could even combine both passes into one, lazily adding a new ZOS to the map when you encounter a new type. Then you just go through and close them all when you finish.

Answer (score 0):

Build a map from type to a set of objects of that type. Iterate the list and add each object to the appropriate bucket.

If you want a solution that uses less memory, you can sort the list by type to group the objects in chunks containing items of the same type.